# Why starting a docker container changes the host's default route?

Tags: networking, docker, routes

I've configured my host with the following routing table:

```
user@host:~ $ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
{VPN SERVER IP} 192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

So that without being connected to the VPN I'm not connected to the internet:

```
user@host:~ $ ping google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

As soon as I start my docker container the host's routing table changes to:

```
user@host:~ $ netstat -rn
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
{VPN SERVER IP} 192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 vethcbeee28
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

And I'm connected to the internet again:

```
user@host:~ $ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.212.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Basically my host *shouldn't* be able to connect to the internet without being connected to the VPN. But, starting the container sets the default route to my gateway again.

Does somebody know what's going on here? And, how to avoid that?

So far I found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882945/change-default-route-in-docker-container/37047070#37047070) which I'd like to avoid anyway.

**EDIT:**

I just found out that this happens even building an image from a dockerfile!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, and finally found a solution:

```
# Stop and disable dhcpcd daemon on system boot since we going to start it manually with /etc/rc.local
# NB: we do so, cause 'docker' when building or running a container sets up a 'bridge' interface which interferes 'failover'
systemctl stop dhcpcd
systemctl disable dhcpcd

# Start dhcpcd daemon on each interface we are interested in
dhcpcd eth0
dhcpcd eth1
dhcpcd wlan0

# Start dhcpcd daemon on every reboot
sed -i -e 's/^exit 0$//g' /etc/rc.local
echo "dhcpcd eth0" >> /etc/rc.local
echo "dhcpcd eth1" >> /etc/rc.local
echo "dhcpcd wlan0" >> /etc/rc.local
echo "" >> /etc/rc.local
echo "exit 0" >> /etc/rc.local
```

I also added dns servers for docker (probably, not necessary)

```
cat >> /etc/docker/daemon.json << EOF
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
EOF
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `nogateway` option in the `/etc/dhcpd.conf` file.

```
# Avoid to set the default routes.
nogateway
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. @dario, did you ever find a solution, except mentioned above?