# How to make docker container connect everything through proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I know it is possible to pass http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables to a container as shown in eg. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47828827/234466). However, this only works for proxy-aware commands like wget and curl as they merely read and use these environment variables.

I need to connect everything through the proxy, so that all internet access is routed via the proxy. Essentially, the proxy should be transformed into a kind of VPN.

I am thinking about something similar to the `--net=container` option where the container gets its network from another container.

How do I configure a container to run everything through the proxy?

Comment: Maybe you can change the default route like in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882945/change-default-route-in-docker-container

Comment: @HansKilian How would I change the default route to use a proxy like this http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com? Any ideas appreciated :)

Comment: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-transparently-use-a-proxy-with-any-application-docker-using-iptables-and-redsocks-b8301ddc4e1e

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to put all your containers behind a proxy? If that's the case I would put them all on their own virtual network along with an nginx container that exposes each of your containers on it's own endpoint.

Comment: @JanGaraj Your link actually provides valuable info. I think I can get along from there.

Comment: @BrandonPina No, just a single container. I think the keyword is transparent proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jan Garaj's comment actually pointed me in the right direction.

As noted in my question, not all programs and commands use the proxy environment variables so simply passing the http_proxy and https_proxy env vars to docker is not a solution. I needed a solution where the whole docker container is directing *every* network requests (on certain ports) through the proxy. No matter which program or command.

The [Medium article](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-transparently-use-a-proxy-with-any-application-docker-using-iptables-and-redsocks-b8301ddc4e1e) demonstrates how to build and setup a docker container that, by the help of [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks), will redirect all ftp requests to another running docker container acting as a proxy. The communication between the containers is done via a docker network.

In my case I already have a running proxy so I don't need a docker network and a docker proxy. Also, I need to proxy http and https, not ftp.

By changing the configuration files I got it working. In this example I simply call `wget ipecho.net/plain` to retrieve my outside IP. If it works, this should be the IP of the proxy, not my real IP.

**Configuration**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest
LABEL maintainer="marlar"
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -qy
RUN apt-get install iptables redsocks curl wget lynx -qy
COPY redsocks.conf /etc/redsocks.conf
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash run.sh
```

setup script (run.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Configuration:"
echo "PROXY_SERVER=$PROXY_SERVER"
echo "PROXY_PORT=$PROXY_PORT"
echo "Setting config variables"
sed -i "s/vPROXY-SERVER/$PROXY_SERVER/g" /etc/redsocks.conf
sed -i "s/vPROXY-PORT/$PROXY_PORT/g" /etc/redsocks.conf
echo "Restarting redsocks and redirecting traffic via iptables"
/etc/init.d/redsocks restart
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
echo "Getting IP ..."
wget -q -O- https://ipecho.net/plain
```

redsocks.conf:

```
base {
 log_debug = off;
 log_info = on;
 log = "file:/var/log/redsocks.log";
 daemon = on;
 user = redsocks;
 group = redsocks;
 redirector = iptables;
}
redsocks {
 local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
 local_port = 12345;
 ip = vPROXY-SERVER;
 port = vPROXY-PORT;
 type = http-connect;

}
```

**Building the container**

```
build -t proxy-via-iptables .
```

**Running the container**

```
docker run -i -t  --privileged -e PROXY_SERVER=x.x.x.x -e PROXY_PORT=xxxx proxy-via-iptables
```

Replace the proxy server and port with the relevant numbers.

If the container works and uses the external proxy, wget should spit out the IP of the proxy *even though the wget command does not use the `-e use_proxy=yes` option*. If it doesn't work, it will give you your own IP. Or perhaps no IP at all, depending on how it fails.

Comment: I've tried following these steps, but I keep getting 502 response errors on every request... My setup seems similar to yours where I'm running a mitmproxy proxy server on my local machine while trying to capture network traffic made from a docker container.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the proxy env var:

```
docker container run \
  -e HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com \
  -e HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com \
 yourimage
```

If you want the proxy-server to be automatically used when starting a container, you can configure default proxy-servers in the Docker CLI configuration file (~/.docker/config.json). You can find *[instructions](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)* for this in the networking section in the user guide

for exemple :

```
{
  "proxies": {
    "default": {
      "httpProxy": "http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com",
      "httpsProxy": "http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com"
    }
  }
}
```

To verify if the ~/.docker/config.json configuration is working, start a container and print its env:

```
docker container run --rm busybox env

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=220e4df13604
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy2.domain.com
HOME=/root
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the proxy environment variables doesn't work as stated in my question.  Not all programs use the vars. I need the whole container to redirect everything to the proxy.